# How to make a PHP show user data from database?

Tags: php, mysql, login-system

I made a login system, how do I make it show the username after login, so it goes like on the main login screen -> database check -> success page. On this success page how do I make it show the username, that was registered? I have only added

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>
```

On the 3rd page which is the success page, I need it to show the username that has logged on and other user information from the table.

Comment: Go see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208369/retrieve-data-from-mysql-using-php

Comment: After the login check the username is stored on the session

Comment: Once the session variable is stored, you can read it on any page with a little php like - $userid = $_SESSION['useridentifier'].

Answer (score 1):

you need to store the username in the session variable then after **successful login** display it. you can use `isset()` to serve that purpose to check whether the session variable is set or not.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
?>
```

Comment: Dont forget to call session_start(); first

Comment: @JohnnyHarlamert thanks for that but i thought that was obvious :)

Comment: For you and I, but not for someone who asked how to read a session variable

Comment: @JohnnyHarlamert ya totally agree :) +1

Comment: Hi, do you have skype? So i can send you the database check and it will be easier for me, thanks. My skype is ashwindc.

Comment: i am not in skype but i am in gmail send me at rishabhraj51@gmail.com

Comment: i think shankar damodaran has modified your code ,you can take an idea from that also.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){
    echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['myusername'];
}
else
{
   header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>
```

And don't use **`session_is_registered()`** as it is **`Deprecated.`**

Answer (score 0):

Once you successfully logged in then store the username in the session variable.
On the page first check whether session is set then show the username else redirect the user to login page.

```
 <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['myusername']) && $_SESSION['myusername'] != ''){
      echo $_SESSION['myusername'];
}else{
      header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
     session_start();
     //if using post method in login it is better to check if $_POST is set
     $username = $_POST['myusername'];
     if(isset($_POST['myusername'])){
      if(!empty($username)){
       if(isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){
        echo $_SESSION['myusername'];
       }
      }
     }
 ?>
```

You can provide security by checking if your login details are not empty.